# Jquery and javascript in html, calling function multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

Let me start out with, my java skills are almost nonexistant.
I have a site that I want to put multiple forms on and have them open a popup window. We are using javascript/jquery to make the popup when selecting an item from dropdown. We have been able to get it to work on one form, but not multiple so I was trying to set it as a function.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

        // This handles the issue popup on the Single Candidate page.    
        jQuery( "#<?php the_field('last_name', 100); ?>selectBox" ).change(function() {
            jQuery(".issue-select").removeClass("issue-selected");
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("issue-selected");
            jQuery(".issue-block").hide();`enter code here`
            var issue = jQuery(this).val();
            var issueText = jQuery(this).children(':selected').text();
            jQuery("#<?php the_field('last_name', 100); ?>" + issue + "-block").bPopup({
                    modalClose: true,
                    position: ['auto', 'auto'], //x, y
                    opacity: 0.6,
                    scrollbar: true,
                    positionStyle: 'absolute' //'fixed' or 'absolute',
                });


        });  
        };</script>
```

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to make it a function and then having it call out to my select form:

```
> <form>
                        <select id="<?php the_field('last_name', 100); ?>selectBox" name="fieldname" size="1" class="select" style="background-color:#ffffff;font-size: 12px;margin-top: 0px !important;width: 95%;">
                            <option value>Issues</option>
                            <option id="agriculture" class="issue-select" value="agriculture">Agriculture</option>
                            <option id="budget" class="issue-select" value="budget">Budget</option>
                            <option id="corporate_welfare" class="issue-select" value="corporate_welfare">Corporate Welfare</option>
                            <option id="education" class="issue-select" value="education">Education</option>
                            <option id="entitlements_welfare" class="issue-select" value="entitlements_welfare">Entitlements & Welfare</option>
                            <option id="environment_energy" class="issue-select" value="environment_energy">Environment & Energy</option>
                            <option id="federalism" class="issue-select" value="federalism">Federalism</option>
                            <option id="finance_banking" class="issue-select" value="finance_banking">Finance & Banking</option>
                            <option id="free_speech_religious_liberty" class="issue-select" value="free_speech_religious_liberty">Free Speech & Religious Liberty</option>
                            <option id="health_care" class="issue-select" value="health_care">Health Care</option>
                            <option id="immigration" class="issue-select" value="immigration">Immigration</option>
                            <option id="international_relations" class="issue-select" value="international_relations">International Relations</option>
                            <option id="judiciary" class="issue-select" value="judiciary">Judiciary</option>
                            <option id="labor" class="issue-select" value="labor">Labor</option>
                            <option id="military_preparedness_budget" class="issue-select" value="military_preparedness_budget">Military Preparedness & Budget</option>
                            <option id="regulations" class="issue-select" value="regulations">Regulations</option>
                            <option id="privatization" class="issue-select" value="privatization">Privatization</option>
                            <option id="taxes" class="issue-select" value="taxes">Taxes</option>
                            <option id="trade" class="issue-select" value="trade">Trade</option>
                            <option id="war_on_terror" class="issue-select" value="war_on_terror">War On Terror</option>
                        </select>
                        </form>
                        <div class="issue-block" id="agriculture-block"><span class="b-close" style="cursor: pointer;float:right;"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-content/themes/c3/img/close-x.png' ) ); ?>" alt="close button"/></span><h4 class="popup-issue"><?php the_title(); echo ' on Agriculture</h4>'; ?><?php the_field( "agriculture", 100 ); ?></div>  

                        <div class="issue-block" id="budget-block"><span class="b-close" style="cursor: pointer;float:right;"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-content/themes/c3/img/close-x.png' ) ); ?>" alt="close button"/></span><h4 class="popup-issue"><?php the_title(); echo ' on Budget</h4>'; ?><?php the_field( "budget", 100 ); ?></div>    

                        <div class="issue-block" id="corporate_welfare-block"><span class="b-close" style="cursor: pointer;float:right;"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-content/themes/c3/img/close-x.png' ) ); ?>" alt="close button"/></span><h4 class="popup-issue"><?php the_title(); echo ' on Corporate Welfare</h4>'; ?><?php the_field( "corporate_welfare", 100 ); ?></div>

                        <div class="issue-block" id="education-block"><span class="b-close" style="cursor: pointer;float:right;"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-content/themes/c3/img/close-x.png' ) ); ?>" alt="close button"/></span><h4 class="popup-issue"><?php echo the_title(); echo ' on Education</h4>'; ?><?php the_field( "education", 100 ); ?></div>

                        <div class="issue-block" id="environment_energy-block"><span class="b-close" style="cursor: pointer;float:right;"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-content/themes/c3/img/close-x.png' ) ); ?>" alt="close button"/></span><h4 class="popup-issue"><?php the_title(); echo ' on Environment & Energy</h4>'; ?><?php the_field( "environment_&_energy", 100 ); ?></div>       

                        <div class="issue-block" id="entitlements_welfare-block"><span class="b-close" style="cursor: pointer;float:right;"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-content/themes/c3/img/close-x.png' ) ); ?>" alt="close button"/></span><h4 class="popup-issue"><?php the_title(); echo ' on Entitlements & Welfare</h4>'; ?><?php the_field( "entitlements_&_welfare", 100 ); ?></div>

                        <div class="issue-block" id="federalism-block"><span class="b-close" style="cursor: pointer;float:right;"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-content/themes/c3/img/close-x.png' ) ); ?>" alt="close button"/></span><h4 class="popup-issue"><?php the_title(); echo ' on Federalism</h4>'; ?><?php the_field( "federalism", 100 ); ?></div> 

                        <div class="issue-block" id="finance_banking-block"><span class="b-close" style="cursor: pointer;float:right;"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-content/themes/c3/img/close-x.png' ) ); ?>" alt="close button"/></span><h4 class="popup-issue"><?php the_title(); echo ' on Finance & Banking</h4>'; ?><?php the_field( "finance_&_banking", 100 ); ?></div>

                        <div class="issue-block" id="free_speech_religious_liberty-block"><span class="b-close" style="cursor: pointer;float:right;"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-content/themes/c3/img/close-x.png' ) ); ?>" alt="close button"/></span><h4 class="popup-issue"><?php the_title(); echo ' on Free Speech & Religious Liberty</h4>'; ?><?php the_field( "free_speech_&_religious_liberty", 100 ); ?></div> 

                        <div class="issue-block" id="health_care-block"><span class="b-close" style="cursor: pointer;float:right;"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-content/themes/c3/img/close-x.png' ) ); ?>" alt="close button"/></span><h4 class="popup-issue"><?php the_title(); echo ' on Health Care</h4>'; ?><?php the_field( "health_care", 100 ); ?></div>

                        <div class="issue-block" id="immigration-block"><span class="b-close" style="cursor: pointer;float:right;"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-content/themes/c3/img/close-x.png' ) ); ?>" alt="close button"/></span><h4 class="popup-issue"><?php the_title(); echo ' on Immigation</h4>'; ?><?php the_field( "immigration", 100 ); ?></div>   

                        <div class="issue-block" id="international_relations-block"><span class="b-close" style="cursor: pointer;float:right;"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-content/themes/c3/img/close-x.png' ) ); ?>" alt="close button"/></span><h4 class="popup-issue"><?php the_title(); echo ' on International Relations</h4>'; ?><?php the_field( "international_relations", 100 ); ?></div>  

                        <div class="issue-block" id="judiciary-block"><span class="b-close" style="cursor: pointer;float:right;"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-content/themes/c3/img/close-x.png' ) ); ?>" alt="close button"/></span><h4 class="popup-issue"><?php the_title(); echo ' on Judiciary</h4>'; ?><?php the_field( "judiciary", 100 ); ?></div> 

                        <div class="issue-block" id="regulations-block"><span class="b-close" style="cursor: pointer;float:right;"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-content/themes/c3/img/close-x.png' ) ); ?>" alt="close button"/></span><h4 class="popup-issue"><?php the_title(); echo ' on Regulations</h4>'; ?><?php the_field( "regulations", 100 ); ?></div>

                        <div class="issue-block" id="privatization-block"><span class="b-close" style="cursor: pointer;float:right;"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-content/themes/c3/img/close-x.png' ) ); ?>" alt="close button"/></span><h4 class="popup-issue"><?php the_title(); echo ' on Privatization</h4>'; ?><?php the_field( "privatization", 100 ); ?></div>

                        <div class="issue-block" id="taxes-block"><span class="b-close" style="cursor: pointer;float:right;"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-content/themes/c3/img/close-x.png' ) ); ?>" alt="close button"/></span><h4 class="popup-issue"><?php the_title(); echo ' on Taxes</h4>'; ?><?php the_field( "taxes", 100 ); ?></div>

                        <div class="issue-block" id="labor-block"><span class="b-close" style="cursor: pointer;float:right;"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-content/themes/c3/img/close-x.png' ) ); ?>" alt="close button"/></span><h4 class="popup-issue"><?php the_title(); echo ' on Labor</h4>'; ?><?php the_field( "labor", 100 ); ?></div>

                        <div class="issue-block" id="trade-block"><span class="b-close" style="cursor: pointer;float:right;"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-content/themes/c3/img/close-x.png' ) ); ?>" alt="close button"/></span><h4 class="popup-issue"><?php the_title(); echo ' on Trade</h4>'; ?><?php the_field( "trade", 100 ); ?></div>

                        <div class="issue-block" id="military_preparedness_budget-block"><span class="b-close" style="cursor: pointer;float:right;"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-content/themes/c3/img/close-x.png' ) ); ?>" alt="close button"/></span><h4 class="popup-issue"><?php the_title(); echo ' on Military Preparedness</h4>'; ?><?php the_field( "military_preparedness_&_budget", 100 ); ?></div>

                        <div class="issue-block" id="war_on_terror-block"><span class="b-close" style="cursor: pointer;float:right;"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-content/themes/c3/img/close-x.png' ) ); ?>" alt="close button"/></span><h4 class="popup-issue"><?php echo the_title(); echo ' on War on Terror</h4>'; ?><?php the_field( "war_on_terror", 100 ); ?></div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. As stated I need to make multiple of these select boxes.

Comment: **java != javascript**

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context. Is that your issue?

Comment: the issue is that i can't even get the popup to open when i try to set it as a function.